# Scoring method of make_pipeline scikit-learn function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, pipeline

What is the scoring method used by the make_pipeline function in scikit learn? If it's linear regression, is it simply R2?

I seem to be getting the same score when i do
`pipe.score(X_test, y_test)`
and
`r2_score(y_test, y_pred)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make_pipeline` returns a `Pipeline` instance.  `Pipeline.score` delegates to the final step's `score` method.  That then is up to the final estimator, but generally speaking in sklearn, classifiers use `accuracy_score` and regressors use `r2_score`.